# Move position of group of objects via control method and tags - Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, object, ms-access, runtime-error, controls

I've assigned a tag to a group of objects:

```
Tag: Section1
```

Then I have a button called 'Nextbutton'

I want to be able to click that button, and move the objects with the tag 'Section1' to the right by a specified amount

So far I have this code:

```
Public sub Nextbutton_Click ()
    Dim ctrl As Control

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If ctrl.Tag = "Section1" Then
            ctrl.Left = +5 
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

So basically, I'm able to move all of the objects to the left; but I'm not sure how to move them to the right. I tried putting a minus number in the ctrl.Left section but it just gives me this error:

```
Run-time error '2100':
The control or Subform control is too large for this location
```

It's probably a really simple fix, but because I'm new to access and vba; I'm not sure what to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement:

```
ctrl.Left = +5
```

doesn't work in VBA like in most other programming language.

In VBA it just means set property `Left` to 5 (not increment the value of property `Left` by 5), so all the controls with tag `Section1` are placed 5 pixels from the left.

If you want to increase their left position (so move them to the right) you need to replace it with this:

```
ctrl.Left = ctrl.Left + 5
```